# How to focus to a particular item in a particular group of a Telerik RadjumpList in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am Using Telerik RadJumpList to list Groups of items.I am having a "fetchMoreButton" to insert more values to each group.Each group having separate FetchMoreButton.My problem is after inserting more values , i am not able to focus to the inserted value.the focus goes to first item in first group.